# How to display a div as overlay which is hovered by a div which is inside another div?

Tags: html, css

How to display a div as overlay which is hovered by a div which is inside another div.
This is the sample code which I tried to display the div as overlay box

**CSS**

```
   /*This is container Div */
    #one{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#999;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    z-index:1;
    }

    /*This is Hovering Div which is inside container Div:*/
    #oneone
    {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#fff;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    left:100px;
    top:90px;
    z-index:5;
    }

    /*This is the Overlay Div*/
    #two{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#000;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    left:200px;
    top:290px;
    z-index:20;
    display:none;
    }

    /*This is the Div displays after Hovering*/
    #oneone:hover #two{
    display:block;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="one">
    <div id="oneone"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="two">
    </div>
```

Pls help.. thanks in advance.

The Jfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/stylerkishore/DySxJ/

Comment: Can you please make a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: It is recommended to create a http://jsfiddle.net/ for something you have troubles with working so others can help you faster. @dwhite.me hi5

Comment: #oneone:hover #two -- here you asume that #two is inside #oneone, but it is not

Comment: To Florin.prisecariu: I need to show a div outside of the one and oneone. So I shown it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9mhj/) for you

i modified a bit the html, so that #oneone and #two to be at least siblings in the same container

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="oneone"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>    
</div>
```

also i changed the css selector

```
#oneone:hover + #two {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: I tried it was working.  But div 'two' should be out of the div 'one' and 'oneone'. Pls.

Comment: you may need to use js to select parent containers...
the css selectors work on children (>) or siblings (+), but not on parents

Answer (score 1):

Try following code -

```
<div id="one">
<div id="oneone" onmouseover="javascript:var mydiv = document.createElement('two'); "><div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

You will need to edit #two in css to show it's proper position

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gWgy2/)

Comment: div 'two' should be out of the div 'one' and 'oneone'. Pls.

Comment: there is no way to select a parent div with css selectors , more on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector